# Want to connect to my mongodb server from my app server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, nginx, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I have 2 rackspace servers.

- [Server 1] An app server that sits behind a reverse front-end proxy using nginx.
- [Server 2] A server that just has mongodb installed on it (with these directions: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/rackspace-cloud/)

I'm trying to connect to my database with mongoose like (in my app.js on [Server 1]):

```
// DB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var dbSession = 'mongodb://root:password@[Server 2]:27017'
mongoose.createConnection(dbSession);
```

On [Server 2] in /etc/mongo.conf, the only things that are turned on are:

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
# Bind ip for our app server
bind_ip=[Server 1]
```

How can I:
A) Check to see if I'm able to connect to [Server 2] from [Server 1] and actually get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about your firewall configuration, but you may need to open port 27017 on the mongodb server (Server 2 in your setup). Something like the following:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -s [APP_SERVER IP ADDRESS HERE] -j ACCEPT
```

If you haven't setup firewall rules yet, I suggest reading the Ubuntu guide for Iptables:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Also, if you aren't already, you'll probably want to use the private IP address communicate between the servers:

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-the-private-ip-address-on-your-cloud-server

**UPDATE -- 09/22/2013**

I spun up 2 Rackspace servers and performed the steps below to successfully communicate between them.

tl;dr
The problem might be the bind_ip parameter in your /etc/mongo.conf file.

If you copy and paste these commands, remove the '[remove this]' piece in the links when installing mongodb.

Server 1:

- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
- echo 'deb http://[remove this]downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
- apt-get install mongodb-10gen
- apt-get update
- apt-get install mongodb-10gen
- mongo [Server 2 public ip]:27017  // to test connection to Server 2
- sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
- apt-get update
- apt-get install nodejs=0.10.18-1chl1~precise1
- npm install mongoose
- npm install connect-mongo
- npm install express
- vim server.js
- node server.js

Here is the server.js file I used:

```
var express = require('express')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var dbSession = 'mongodb://[Server 2]:27017';
mongoose.connect(dbSession);

var Dog = mongoose.model('Dog', {name: String});

var dog = new Dog({name: 'Fido'});
dog.save(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```

Server 2:

- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
- echo 'deb http://[remove this]downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
- apt-get update
- apt-get install mongodb-10gen
- iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -s [Server 1 private ip] -j ACCEPT

Comment: I added that, but I don't think I needed to anyway (as it's wide open and I wanted to get it work first and then lock it down), but I can connect to [Server 2] from [Server 1] with mongo with `mongo [Server 2 IP]` and I successfully was able to insert something into a collection. I think it's in my Mongoose code, but I'm connecting properly according to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/ `mongodb://root:rootpw@[SERVER 2 IP]:27017`. I'm running my app as root with `node app.js` and I get `throw new Error('Error connecting to database');`

Comment: I'll spin up some servers tonight to test

Comment: Wow. Great answer! Yes that worked! I must have messed up the iptables or something (not sure what) but I re-built both instances and then followed these instructions and it worked perfectly. Thank you sir for your thorough answer!

Comment: You are certainly welcome. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help.